# Arrays with javascript and php

Tags: php

I have this function that creates `textareas` deepening on the month. So if it is march, then 31 textareas. But the problem is right now that I cannot add anything into my db. I tried to make my function into arrays, and he change my php so it is like the function. But im not sure on where the issue lies. The problem is that it inserts empty values in the MySQL db.

function:

```
var showDate = new Date();
var months = ["Januari", "Februari", "March", "April", "May", "June",
              "July", "Augusti", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var weeks = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuseday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];


  function drawTable(forDate) {
    const daysInMonth = new Date(
        forDate.getFullYear(),
        forDate.getMonth() + 1,
        0
    ).getDate();

    const date = [
        forDate.getFullYear(),
        (forDate.getMonth() + 1 + '').padStart(2, 0)
    ]
    .join('-');

    const table = document.getElementById("table");
    table.innerHTML = "";

    for (let day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; day++) {
        const dateString = date + '-' + (day + '').padStart(2, 0);

        const row = document.createElement("tr");
        const cell = document.createElement("td");
        const textarea = document.createElement("textarea");

        textarea.setAttribute("name", "day[]");
        textarea.setAttribute("value", dateString);
        textarea.innerHTML = dateString;
        textarea.setAttribute("placeholder", day);

        cell.appendChild(textarea);
        row.appendChild(cell);
        table.appendChild(row);
    }

    return table;
}
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("displayingMonth").innerHTML = months[showDate.getMonth()];
    drawTable(showDate );
};



         function daysInMonth(month, year) {
         var days;
         switch (month) {
           case 1: // Feb, our problem child
           var leapYear = ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
           days = leapYear ? 29 : 28;
           break;
           case 3:
           case 5:
           case 8:
           case 10:
           days = 30;
           break;
           default:
           days = 31;
          }
          return days;
        }
```

php:

```
   <?php


    $days = $_request['day'];
    echo $error =  "day is empty";


    if(is_array($days)){
    foreach ($days as $day) {
        $day = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $day);

        if (empty($day)) {
          echo $error;

        }

        else {
            !mysqli_query(
                            $conn, "INSERT INTO table (day) VALUES('$day')");

            }

    }
    }

    if (count($error)) {
        print_r($error);
    }

     ?>
```

html:

```
  <h1 id="displayingMonth"></h1>
     <form action="index.php" method="post">
      <table id="table"></table>
      <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Press" />
  </form>
```

> I get my error msg: "day is empty"

Comment: what have you tried to debug your code ? we can't do all debugging stuff

Comment: @Pierre I added diffrent error msg all over the code to see where to problem is, and found out that the code stops here: "if (empty($day)) {
          echo $error;

        }
"

Comment: You always show your error message: `echo $error =  "day is empty";`. I don't think you want to `echo` that initialisation.

Comment: Probably because you're `echo`ing it: `echo $error =  "day is empty";`

Comment: @trincot you where right! I removed it and now im not getting that error msg, but the db is still empty

Comment: @kerbholz you where right! I removed it and now im not getting that error msg, but the db is still empty

Comment: !mysqli_query - Why this ! (Not)?

Comment: Where are you POSTing the JavaScript array `days` to `index.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at this line

```
textarea.setAttribute("name", "day[]");
```

you are in fact passing the `day` array to PHP

Change your PHP to this:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $error = '';

        $days = $_POST['day'];

        if (is_array($days)){
            foreach ($days as $day) {
                $day = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $day);

                echo $day . '<br />';

                if (empty($day)) {
                    echo $error;
                } else {
                    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO table (day) VALUES ('$day')");
                }
            }
        }

        if (count($error)) {
            print_r($error);
        }
    }

?>
```

The code checks if the submit button has been pressed (add `name="submit"` to your submit button) and then retrieves the `day` array submitted in the POST. You should consider changing `$_REQUEST` to `$_POST`, as this is a `POST` request. Note the uppercase `$_REQUEST` as opposed to `$_request`. The latter gave an error for me, so perhaps you don't have errors enabled. Try adding

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to the top of your PHP script and setting

```
`display_errors = on`
```

inside your `php.ini` file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Aaron! Tried this, but still nothing in the db

Comment: @Hanna Code updated. It works for me. Please try and see what you get

Comment: Im getting value in the db now! But, unfortunately, I get all the values from the month in to the db. Like if I only click on day 4, I get everything from 2018-02-01 to 2018-02-28 inserted in the db as values.

Comment: @Hanna How are you allowing the user to choose the day to be inserted into the DB? You could use a `<input type="hidden" />` element, which will contain the date/day selected by the user. That value will then be passed to PHP and you can insert the specific date into the database

Comment: This line is in the html form, as you suggested before:       <input type="hidden" name="days" id="days" value="" />. Or am I misunderstanding you question?

Comment: You need a way to be able to tell PHP what the selected date is. You can use JavaScript to get which date the user selected and then POST that value to PHP and insert only that date into the DB.

Comment: But isnt the date selected when the user clicks on the certain textarea?

Comment: No. Why don't you add a `<select>` with all the days? The user can select the day they want, and then when they click submit, their selected day will be sent to PHP, as long as the `select` has a `name` attribute set

Comment: Well thats because I want the textareas to be displayed nicely next one and other. Is there a way to do that with a select?